# How can i configure on change event on a @mui/material/Autocomplete

Tags: spfx, reactjs, material-ui

First let me say i am a newbie to spfx, and react.
I created spfx component, with multiple input fields that on typing on the fields generate a specific search query and then show me the results.
This is working fine and has been in use for a bit.

Now my boss wants me to change 3 of the input fields we have from a simple text input to a autocomplete type of component.

Here is the code for one of the input fields

```
<input id='countryNameInput' className={styles.textfield} type="text" value={this.state.ctyName} ref={(countryNameInput) => (this.countryNameInput = countryNameInput)} onChange={this.handleInputChange('ctyName')} placeholder='Country Name' />
```

i was triying to replace it with a material ui autocomplete,

```
        <Autocomplete
          options={countryNameOptions}
          style={{ width: "100%" }}

          renderInput={(params) => (
            <div ref={params.InputProps.ref}>
              <input
                id='cty-lists'
                type='text'
                placeholder='Country Name...'
                style={{
                  border: "1px solid #cccccc",
                  padding: "0px",
                }}

                {...params.inputProps}
              />
            </div>
          )}
        />
```

but i cannot seem to be able to trigger the onChange event so it can detect the changes and generte the query

here is the code for the handleInputChange method

```
 private handleInputChange = (fieldName: keyof ITagQueryGeneratorWebPartState) => async (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement>
  ): Promise<void> => {

    console.log(fieldName + " " + e.target.value);
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [fieldName]: pe.target.value,
    }));

    this.generateSearchQuery();
    await this.handleSearch();
  };
```

Any help on getting this to work will be apreciated
ps. i am a bit short on time to get this working

Comment: I did a quick google for the material ui react autocomplete documentation and don't see any mention of a callback. If you are working off documentation, post the link to it so people don't have to guess what you're trying to do.